# C# Azure: How to read body from Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message?

Tags: c#, azure, serialization, message-bus

I have trouble with the `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message` class. I want to create a Message object containing a payload object and then read this object back from it. In my current example I am not even sending the Message through a real Azure bus; I'm just creating it in memory and then trying to read it.

I cannot figure out what type I am supposed to read the message body as. I've tried `byte[]`, `string` and the original object type. In all my cases I get an `XmlException`: "The input source is not correctly formatted".

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong, either when encoding or decoding the Message?

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Thingy
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Doodad { get; set; }
    }

    private static Message CreateMessage()
    {
        var entityMessage = new Thingy {Doodad = "foobar"};
        var serializedMessageBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entityMessage);
        var contentType = typeof(Thingy).AssemblyQualifiedName;
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedMessageBody);
        var message = new Message(bytes) {ContentType = contentType};
        return message;
    }

    [Test]
    public void ReadMessageBytes()
    {
        var message = CreateMessage();
        var body = message.GetBody<byte[]>();
        Console.WriteLine(body);
    }

    [Test]
    public void ReadMessageString()
    {
        var message = CreateMessage();
        var body = message.GetBody<string>();
        Console.WriteLine(body);
    }

    [Test]
    public void ReadMessageThingy()
    {
        var message = CreateMessage();
        var body = message.GetBody<Thingy>();
        Console.WriteLine(body);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that this works:

```
    [Test]
    public void ReadMessageProperly()
    {
        var message = CreateMessage();
        var body = message.Body;
        var text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
        var thingy = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Thingy>(text);
        Assert.IsInstanceOf<Thingy>(thingy);
        Assert.AreEqual("foobar", thingy.Doodad);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

When creating a BrokeredMessage using custom `DataContract` type and using `DataContractSerializer` :

```
Record recordDataContract = new Record { Id = "DataContract Record" };

BrokeredMessage recordDataContractMessage = new BrokeredMessage(recordDataContract, new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Record)));
```

You can receive this message as:

```
Record r = receiveMessage.GetBody<Record>(new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Record)));
```

When creating a `**BrokeredMessage**` using custom `**DataContract**` type and using default serializer (DataContract + Binary Xml):

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]

class Record {

[DataMember]

public string Id { get; set; }

}


Record recordDefault = new Record { Id = "default Record" };

BrokeredMessage recordDefaultMessage = new BrokeredMessage(recordDefault);
```

You can receive this message as:

```
Record r = receiveMessage.GetBody<Record>();
```

For additional reference , you can check [this blog](https://abhishekrlal.com/2012/03/30/formatting-the-content-for-service-bus-messages/). It has detailed example for different scenarios.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer uses `Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage` rather than `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message`.

As far as I can tell, I need `Message` because I rely on `QueueClient.RegisterMessageHandler`, which uses `Message` rather than `BrokeredMessage`.

Comment: Your suggestion corresponds to my test method `ReadMessageThingy`, which failed. Moreover, your setup is completely different because `BrokeredMessage` has a different interface than `Message`.